# Yii2 multiple sites and GIT pull

Tags: git, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this Yii2 folder structure:

- backend
- frontend
- api
- site1
- site2
- vendor
- common

Each of this folder is to be considered an app.
I want to be able to GIT it separately or together on this folders/apps.

The idea is to create separated repo for each folder/app to be more easy and independent the management of single app and branches like dev, bug fix, prod for each of it.

Is this a best practice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot understand your question. Please take some time to [edit] your question to clarify what you want. The main problem for me is that you have one very long sentence. Try to write your explanation with several shorter sentences to describe the problem.

Comment: You should use branches to separate stable and unstable code.

Comment: i have edited my question. thanks

Comment: it is a good idea to create a repository for each folder and then use branches to manage develope, bugfix etc. for each?

Answer (score 0):

If these are separated applications, splitting them into separate and independent repositories may be a good idea - usually it is easier to maintain a couple of smaller and independent systems than one big monolith.

But this is true only if these are actually separated applications, and I would guess that it is not the case. If these applications are connected with each other (like API uses some components from backend) or most of the code and development is in `common` directory (which is shared between all apps), then splitting apps may be not trivial and/or does not fix your problem at all.

If the only problem is releasing and deploying stable version, you can use branches for that. For example keep only stable and tested code in `master`. Every feature, bugfix or sprint should be done on separate branches and merged to master after tests and acceptance. In that case you have always stable code in `master` branch and you should be always be able do deploy code from `master` to production.